# How do I get Apache2 to parse (without error) Header directives in a .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http-headers

I am getting pages loading with a 500 internal server error, due I believe to a directive that Apache has not been configured to allow.

I have AllowOverride set to all, and a .htaccess file, including:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|swf|ttf|woff)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
Header set Expires "Wed, 23 Apr 2014 17:00:01 UTC"
</FilesMatch>
```

/var/log/apache2/error.log has:

```
[Sat Jul 20 15:12:36 2013] [alert] [client 24.15.83.241] /home/jonathan/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

What do I need to specify so that Apache2 will properly handle the 'Header' directive?

Answer (score 76):

With apache2, just run `a2enmod headers` and then `sudo service apache2 restart` and it will install the headers module automatically.

Comment: This answer should be accepted

Comment: Indeed this answer is the best, however I dare to say that some modern GNU/Linux distros (like the latest Debian) are based on `systemd` and have a different syntax on managing services. Restart Apache: `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`. However, as of now a fallback function exists and thus the old `sudo service` command does work. But it may stop working in the nearest future.

Comment: `a2enmod` is in `/usr/sbin` on my system. That's not in my non-sudoer user's PATH, so a2enmod isn't discoverable unless you're root. TL;DR: run `sudo a2enmod` instead of just `a2enmod`.

Answer (score 15):

You'll need to add a line like:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

To your `httpd.conf` to add support for that. In Ubuntu and similar, you can do `a2enmod headers` and it'll automatically enable it in your configuration.